# Stripe API - Query ALL line items under checkout session

Tags: powerbi, stripe-payments, powerquery

I'm using the code below to extract the data from checkout sessions, however, the products and prices columns are only available under "line items" as per Stripe's API documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list?lang=curl

E.g.

```
https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/cs_test_a1cNMv4otp1TRPRrLJrMbRwgXAZjta41j6m57srdgfxjcXmAq6chFWq6cJ/line_items?limit=5 \
```

The way I see it, Stripe only allows to query the line items of specific checkout sessions by querying a specific CheckoutSessionID (CS_ID). I'd need to query ALL the CheckoutSessionIDs, but can't seem to do it via PowerQuery.

```
    let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromRecords({Source}),
    #"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "data"),
    #"Expanded data1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data", "data", {"id", "object", "after_expiration", "allow_promotion_codes", "amount_subtotal", "amount_total", "automatic_tax", "billing_address_collection", "cancel_url", "client_reference_id", "consent", "consent_collection", "created", "currency", "currency_conversion", "custom_fields", "custom_text", "customer", "customer_creation", "customer_details", "customer_email", "expires_at", "invoice", "invoice_creation", "livemode", "locale", "metadata", "mode", "payment_intent", "payment_link", "payment_method_collection", "payment_method_options", "payment_method_types", "payment_status", "phone_number_collection", "recovered_from", "setup_intent", "shipping_address_collection", "shipping_cost", "shipping_details", "shipping_options", "status", "submit_type", "subscription", "success_url", "total_details", "url"}, {"data.id", "data.object", "data.after_expiration", "data.allow_promotion_codes", "data.amount_subtotal", "data.amount_total", "data.automatic_tax", "data.billing_address_collection", "data.cancel_url", "data.client_reference_id", "data.consent", "data.consent_collection", "data.created", "data.currency", "data.currency_conversion", "data.custom_fields", "data.custom_text", "data.customer", "data.customer_creation", "data.customer_details", "data.customer_email", "data.expires_at", "data.invoice", "data.invoice_creation", "data.livemode", "data.locale", "data.metadata", "data.mode", "data.payment_intent", "data.payment_link", "data.payment_method_collection", "data.payment_method_options", "data.payment_method_types", "data.payment_status", "data.phone_number_collection", "data.recovered_from", "data.setup_intent", "data.shipping_address_collection", "data.shipping_cost", "data.shipping_details", "data.shipping_options", "data.status", "data.submit_type", "data.subscription", "data.success_url", "data.total_details", "data.url"}),
    #"Expanded data.automatic_tax" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data1", "data.automatic_tax", {"enabled", "status"}, {"data.automatic_tax.enabled", "data.automatic_tax.status"}),
    #"Expanded data.custom_text" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.automatic_tax", "data.custom_text", {"shipping_address", "submit"}, {"data.custom_text.shipping_address", "data.custom_text.submit"}),
    #"Expanded data.invoice_creation" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.custom_text", "data.invoice_creation", {"enabled", "invoice_data"}, {"data.invoice_creation.enabled", "data.invoice_creation.invoice_data"}),
    #"Expanded data.invoice_creation.invoice_data" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.invoice_creation", "data.invoice_creation.invoice_data", {"account_tax_ids", "custom_fields", "description", "footer", "metadata", "rendering_options"}, {"data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.account_tax_ids", "data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.custom_fields", "data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.description", "data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.footer", "data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.metadata", "data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.rendering_options"}),
    #"Expanded data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.invoice_creation.invoice_data", "data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.metadata", {}, {}),
    #"Expanded data.metadata" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.metadata", "data.metadata", {"component", "firstname", "itemid", "lastname", "paymentarea", "userid", "username"}, {"data.metadata.component", "data.metadata.firstname", "data.metadata.itemid", "data.metadata.lastname", "data.metadata.paymentarea", "data.metadata.userid", "data.metadata.username"}),
    #"Expanded data.payment_method_options" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.metadata", "data.payment_method_options", {"wechat_pay"}, {"data.payment_method_options.wechat_pay"}),
    #"Expanded data.payment_method_options.wechat_pay" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.payment_method_options", "data.payment_method_options.wechat_pay", {"app_id", "client"}, {"data.payment_method_options.wechat_pay.app_id", "data.payment_method_options.wechat_pay.client"}),
    #"Expanded data.phone_number_collection" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.payment_method_options.wechat_pay", "data.phone_number_collection", {"enabled"}, {"data.phone_number_collection.enabled"}),
    #"Expanded data.total_details" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.phone_number_collection", "data.total_details", {"amount_discount", "amount_shipping", "amount_tax"}, {"data.total_details.amount_discount", "data.total_details.amount_shipping", "data.total_details.amount_tax"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data.total_details",{{"object", type text}, {"data.id", type text}, {"data.object", type text}, {"data.after_expiration", type any}, {"data.allow_promotion_codes", type logical}, {"data.amount_subtotal", Int64.Type}, {"data.amount_total", Int64.Type}, {"data.automatic_tax.enabled", type logical}, {"data.automatic_tax.status", type text}, {"data.billing_address_collection", type text}, {"data.cancel_url", type text}, {"data.client_reference_id", type any}, {"data.consent", type any}, {"data.consent_collection", type any}, {"data.created", Int64.Type}, {"data.currency", type text}, {"data.currency_conversion", type any}, {"data.custom_fields", type any}, {"data.custom_text.shipping_address", type any}, {"data.custom_text.submit", type any}, {"data.customer", type text}, {"data.customer_creation", type text}, {"data.customer_details", type any}, {"data.customer_email", type any}, {"data.expires_at", Int64.Type}, {"data.invoice", type any}, {"data.invoice_creation.enabled", type logical}, {"data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.account_tax_ids", type any}, {"data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.custom_fields", type any}, {"data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.description", type any}, {"data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.footer", type any}, {"data.invoice_creation.invoice_data.rendering_options", type any}, {"data.livemode", type logical}, {"data.locale", type text}, {"data.metadata.component", type text}, {"data.metadata.firstname", type text}, {"data.metadata.itemid", Int64.Type}, {"data.metadata.lastname", type text}, {"data.metadata.paymentarea", type text}, {"data.metadata.userid", Int64.Type}, {"data.metadata.username", type text}, {"data.mode", type text}, {"data.payment_intent", type text}, {"data.payment_link", type text}, {"data.payment_method_collection", type text}, {"data.payment_method_options.wechat_pay.app_id", type any}, {"data.payment_method_options.wechat_pay.client", type text}, {"data.payment_method_types", type any}, {"data.payment_status", type text}, {"data.phone_number_collection.enabled", type logical}, {"data.recovered_from", type any}, {"data.setup_intent", type any}, {"data.shipping_address_collection", type any}, {"data.shipping_cost", type any}, {"data.shipping_details", type any}, {"data.shipping_options", type any}, {"data.status", type text}, {"data.submit_type", type text}, {"data.subscription", type any}, {"data.success_url", type text}, {"data.total_details.amount_discount", Int64.Type}, {"data.total_details.amount_shipping", Int64.Type}, {"data.total_details.amount_tax", Int64.Type}, {"data.url", type any}, {"has_more", type logical}, {"url", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 0):

A Checkout Session [object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object) has a `line_items` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-line_items) which contains up to 10 line items associated with it.

This property is what Stripe calls [includable](https://stripe.com/docs/expand#includable-properties) which means it's not returned by default in the API and you have to explicitly include it by using their [Expand feature](https://stripe.com/docs/expand).

When calling the List Checkout Sessions [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list) you have to explicitly pass `expand: ['data.line_items']` to ask Stripe to include up to 10 line items for each Checkout Session in the list.

If there are more than 10 line items on a given Checkout Session, you will have to list its line items separately. It's not possible to control the number of items returned in a sub-list.

Comment: I can change the source to "Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/cs_live_S4MpL3/line_items?limit=10"))"

Is there any way to replace that "cs_live_S4MpL3" to a dynamic field that takes each one of the CustomerSessionIDs under /v1/checkout/sessions on PowerQuery?

Comment: I have never heard of PowerQuery unfortunately but you should be able to construct a string for example using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-format or something similar that has the id in the middle

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to get this far creating a dynamic field for each session that seems to be working so far. I can use the product description column, which is not ideal, but in my case it's still unique values, so I can link this between products and sessions.

```
let
    Source = Table.TransformColumns(sessions, {"data.id", each Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions/" & _ & "/line_items")), type any}),
    #"Expanded data.id" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Source, "data.id", {"object", "data", "has_more", "url"}, {"data.id.object", "data.id.data", "data.id.has_more", "data.id.url"}),
    #"Expanded data.id.data" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded data.id", "data.id.data"),
    #"Expanded data.id.data1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded data.id.data", "data.id.data", {"description"}, {"data.id.data.description"})
in
    #"Expanded data.id.data1"
```